# How can a chat room be deleted?

Tags: support, chat

I have created a chat room by mistake, and wish to delete it. Is there any way I can do that as the room owner? If not, can I ask someone to delete it for me? The chat room can be empty, or it can have some comments in it, but I would like to delete it. Is it possible?

Comment: If you don't do anything, it will get frozen and deleted after a period of time. Not sure if there's a quicker way

Comment: Oh, I hope they invent one! Sometimes it can get you out of an embarrassing situation :-)

Comment: Moderators can do it, but there's no reason to do so at the moment -- apart from mods, you are the only person who can talk in it; and I'd be interested to know how non-mods can delete their own rooms. If I delete it, you'd have to create another one to try that.

Comment: [Relevant question on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159975/how-to-ask-moderators-to-delete-a-chat-room)